# How to insert HTML inside an Ext.each() in the labeFormatter function of legend-EXTJS -highcharts

Tags: extjs, highcharts

I was referring to the Highcharts doc but I don't quite understand how to add an HTMl inside an EXT js loop inside the labelFormatter func.
Here is the code:

```
getLegendConfig: function() {
  var ct = this;
  return {
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    layout: 'vertical',
    x: -25,
    y: 25,
    borderWidth: 0,
    floating: type === 'column',
    itemMarginBottom: 5,
    labelFormatter: function() {
      var count = this.y || 0;
      Ext.each(ct.data.series, function(ct) {

        ct.data.map(function(pt) {
          if (pt !== null) {
            return [
              '<div>',
              Ext.util.Format.ellipsis("some name", 48),
              '<span class="qx-highchart-legend-item-count">',
              Ext.util.Format.number(pt.count, '0,000'),
              '</span>',
              '</div>'
            ].join('');
          }

        })


      });

    },
    useHTML: true
  };
}.createDelegate(this)
```

With the above code, nothing gets populated inside the  element, not sure how to get this running. Any ideas? 
Here is the fiddle:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2k5v
Thanks

Comment: It would be much better if you can post a Sencha fiddle with that code. Much easier to get things going quickly when it comes to Sencha issues.

Comment: @Akrion: Here is the fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2k5v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not have in your fiddle the actual highchart but only the `getLegendConfig` portion it would be tricky to give exact answer. However this goes back to the previous question you asked about the panel with values. So this is a similar example where the values are rendered on a panel: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2k60

Here is the main part:

```
series.map((x) => {
  return x.data.map(function(pt) {
    if (pt !== null) {
      return [
        '<div>',
        Ext.util.Format.ellipsis("name", 48),
        '<span class="qx-highchart-legend-item-count">',
        Ext.util.Format.number(pt.count, '0,000'),
        '</span>',
        '</div>'
      ].join('');
    }
  })
}),
```

You have to `compose` that with your code and see if you get the output you want. Based on the example I gave above this will render on a simple panel the values you wanted so it should be working with your pieces. Let me know how it goes.